# What is the practical difference in this DC offset remover?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, dc-offset, signal-generator

I am working on audio signal oscillators. My oscillator generates 0V to +5V triangle wave.
Then I'm removing DC bias to get -5V to +5V signal.
I have found two examples on how to do this:
[image]

What is the practical difference between these two approaches? I get roughly the same result in both of them. So I am wondering what method should I use?

Comment: One adds a DC bias and the other removes it. I'd just use a capacitor and resistor high-pass filter in the absence of other important information.

Comment: As far as I understand B is used to amplify my Vpp and buffer the signal so it could be used in other modules. Is that correct ?

Comment: Both circuits amplify and buffer.

Comment: But doesn't both of them remove DC bias? As both of them give me -5V+5V output at the end

Comment: Adding a dc bias to counter the unwanted bias on an input is still "adding a bias" but subtractively.

Comment: Oh you are correct, that makes sense.